# Passing Same In Function but output are different

Tags: sql, sql-server

Facing issue with @Detail when passing value in function through string 'ABC' the getting correct output but when passing via variable then getting incorrect output. What i am doing wrong.

```
 DECLARE @Detail varchar(4000)

 SELECT @Detail = detail FROM table1
 select @Detail
 
select * from dbo.SDF_SplitString(@Detail,' ',88)
```

INCORRECT OUTPUT

[image]

```
select * from dbo.SDF_SplitString(' 11/13/2019 12:15:0 11/13/2019 12:15:0 11/13/2019 14:30:0 BOM GOP SG  438   24A MR Kamleshwar  Prasad  4',' ',88)
```

CORRECT OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: How did you get the string literal to paste into query 2? if you eg copied it out of SSMS results grid it might have altered some characters

Comment: I get the string through select which i pasted in 2nd query which is giving correct results but when passing it thru variable/ or like select detail from table1 then getting incorrect values

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need the booking ID along with values that later us in other stuff..

Comment: Btw string_split in SQLs is slightly risky because MS do not guarantee the output order = the order inputted. This function might guarantee order

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need BookingHistoryID and OrderBumber in which they are string that will later cross apply with some table having BookingHistoryID that why i required that one

Comment: @CaiusJard The Output count should be 15 rows which is correct but you suggested to changes in output.... I Need to total row as 15 not 6 mentioned in screenshot

Comment: Please, just do as i asked.. Run this query, instead of your first one, and put the output in the question:`select *, ASCII(REPLACE(part, '12:15:0', '')) from dbo.SDF_SplitString(@Detail,' ',88)` - i want to see what the output is

Comment: @AaronBertrand There is not secret in function the issue is function working with manullay passing value in function but not dynamic based on conditions

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed, but when someone wants the assistance of a highly valued and respectable DB professional as yourself (or relatively unknown DB amateur as myself) who is engaged and willing to offer help it's a reasonable courtesy to promptly and directly comply with a request for more info to help debug the issue.. I was merely trying to short circuit an excessive "round-the-houses" :D

Comment: @Caius I apologize, I thought the OP demanded that of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so that query I had you run is showing that the character between `12:15:0 11/13/2019` is a TAB (ascii character 9), not a space (ascii character 32)

This is why you get the output you do; you should perhaps consider to replace tabs with spaces before you split, or upgrade your split function so you can pass multiple chars to it for splitting (I assume that's what the `' '` parameter is for)

When you copied your value out of SSMS results grid it swapped the tabs for spaces already (SSMS converted the tabs to spaces), so when you ran it, it "looked the right output" when using the hardcoded value that contained only spaces..

..but the data in the DB table definitely has tabs! Always be careful copying stuff out of SSMS results grid; it drops characters, changes characters and cuts longer data off at the end, so it cannot be guaranteed to be an accurate reflection of what is in the table.

```
select * from dbo.SDF_SplitString(REPLACE(@Detail, CHAR(9), ' '),' ',88)
```

should give the output you expect..

If you have the option of changing this field so it doesn't have delimited data in it would be safer; splitting can sometimes give unusable results if the positions change